# Repair database on Replica in sharded set up

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongo-repair

I am using mongo sharding in my DB. The scenario I am facing is that I have deleted some of my collections in my DB. But as to reclaim the space I need to run repair option which i can not run using Mongos in production.
So my plan is to run Repair on each replica server one by one by switching primary to replica and vice versa so that production systems is working.
Here I have two confusions:

1. Is it a right approach to repair DB
2. I have a big Data base like 1 TB of Data so repair option might take a day or two in this case my issue is every daya my application creates sharded DB bucket for that day so while running repair on one replica server metadata in config will get updated will it be a error in this case.
3. While deleting some old databases from my cluster I stopped the balancer and restart it after delete but still DB is not completely deleted it is showing me 2 or 3 GB memory space used. I check the remaining DB and it shows no collection in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion if your fragmentation is not over 15-20% its not worth doing that (except if you are running out of disk space). What i would do is:

1) Add an arbiter to each replica set (optional)

2) Shutdown one of the secondaries and delete the data directory

3) Start the secondary and let it do the initial sync which removes fragmentation

(at this point you can evaluate if the gain on disk worth continue)

4) When Secondary catch up do the same for the next Secondary

5) When all Secondaries done, step-down Primary and do the same on the x-Primary

6) Remove the arbiter

Important: Your oplog size must be able to keep all operations during the initial sync. Else you will need to resize it (Same applies if you choose repair option)

For your second question replica set member don't hold any metadata. If the majority of Replica set is always available you will not face any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions My current set is having two shards each shard has replica set (Primary, Secondary and Arbiter). You mean that while starting secondary with initial sync it will not require the Repair option it will automatically do it.Second Issue i have added in the question please check that also

Comment: If you delete the data directory from the SECONDARY and start-up again initial sync will start automatically. (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-sync/) With your configuration 2 DATA nodes and an ARB, you will not be safe either do the initial sync or the repair, because you will have only one DATA node available.

Comment: For 3) You drop database? or the collections on it?

Comment: Ya there were some old databases we removed and from recent database we removed collections;

Comment: Remove database will allow OS to claim disk space. Remove a collection will not. Do you have the profiler on for the removed databases?

Comment: No Profiler is not there My Db was of 20 Gb but when i removed it is still showing 2 Gb space used.                    ibeat20140505  3.952GB                                    db.stats();{"raw": {firstset/192.168.22.113:27017,192.168.33.143:27017" : {
 "db" : "ibeat20140505",
 "collections" : 0,
 "objects" : 0,
  "avgObjSize" : 0,
  "dataSize" : 0,
  "storageSize" : 0,
 "numExtents" : 0,
 "indexes" : 0,
 "indexSize" : 0,
 "fileSize" : 0,
 "dataFileVersion" : {},
 "ok":1}},"objects" : 0,
 "avgObjSize" : 0,
 "dataSize" : 0,
 "storageSize" : 0,
 "numExtents" : 0,
 "indexes" : 0,
 "indexSize" :0

Comment: You mean the ibeat20140505 3.952GB ? because i don't see any 2Gb might get to that issue? https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4804

Comment: It would have been useful to rerun the drop and share the logs from mongos and mongod.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18847/discussion-between-antonis-and-viren).

Comment: Please mark this as answered if covers you